# Is it possible to use a class that is implemented in its parent class (which is an inner class)?

Tags: java, namespaces, inner-classes

Let’s consider a simple class `Action` which is meant to traverse multiple *stages*, a pre-defined order of states, until reaching the last stage. The stages should be represented by subclasses of a common class `Stage` and encapsulate code for the `Action` class to be executed when a method `proceed()` is called. This method also returns the next stage.

I hope this is a reasonable design, as I consider it to be cleaner than having an enum with state constants and a `proceed()` with switch-case.

It can be implemented simply with inner classes:

```
public class Action {

    private int m;
    private Stage stage;

    public Action() {
        stage = new FirstStage();
    }

    public void proceed() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage = stage.proceed();
        }
    }

    public interface Stage {

        /**
         * Executes current stage and returns next stage.
         *
         * @return
         */
        Stage proceed();
    }

    public class FirstStage implements Stage {

        @Override
        public Stage proceed() {
            m = 100;
            return new SecondStage();
        }

    }

    public class SecondStage implements Stage {

        @Override
        public Stage proceed() {
            //do something
            return null; // last stage
        }

    }
}
```

But I am annoyed by all the `Stage` subclasses residing loosely in the `Action` class though they belong together. To solve this and to get a convenient namespacing, it would be useful to implement the stage classes as inner classes of `Stage`. So we would write `Stage.First` instead of `FirstStage` which I consider to be clearer.

```
public class ActionB {

    private int m;
    private Stage stage;

    public ActionB() {
        stage = new Stage.First(); // error
    }

    public void proceed() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage = stage.proceed();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Stage {

        /**
         * Executes current stage and returns next stage.
         *
         * @return
         */
        public abstract Stage proceed();

        public class First extends Stage {

            @Override
            public Stage proceed() {
                m = 100;
                return new Second();
            }

        }

        public class Second extends Stage {

            @Override
            public Stage proceed() {
                //do something
                return null; // last stage
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The first thing I had to change was to make `Stage` an abstract class, because interfaces are static and so the members of `Action` could not be accessed.

The problem now is to instantiate the first stage in the constructor.
Compiler error:

> error: an enclosing instance that contains ActionB.Stage.First is required

Sure I understand that an inner class needs an instance of its outer class. But what if the outer class is abstract or even static (an interface)? Shouldn’t this work?

Is there still a way to achieve the nesting? Or is this bad design anyway?

Comment: Inner classes should be declared static if they do not have any dependency on the outer class!

Comment: But they do have dependencies, they need to access the members! Making `Stage` static makes them unaccessible from the subclasses.

Comment: Yes, but First does not need a dependency to Stage. Make it static.

Comment: `public static class First extends Stage` gives `modifier static not allowed here`...

Comment: You're right. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to use `switch` statements with `enum`s. You can use the clean concept of inheritance with them as well:

```
public class Action {
    private int m;
    private Stage stage;

    public Action() {
        stage = Stage.FIRST;
    }
    public void proceed() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage = stage.proceed(this);
        }
    }

    enum Stage {
      FIRST {
        @Override
        Stage proceed(Action a) {
          a.m = 100;
          return SECOND;
        }
      },
      SECOND {
        @Override
        Stage proceed(Action a) {
          //do something
          return null; // last stage
        }
      }
      ;
      /**
       * Executes current stage and returns next stage.
       */
      abstract Stage proceed(Action a);
    }
}
```

---

The problem with your attempt of nesting classes is unsolvable: when declaring all sub-classes of the `abstract` class `Stage` as non-`static` inner classes, these classes require an outer instance of `Stage` at construction time. However, there is no instance for using as outer instance, as `Stage` is `abstract` and all sub-classes are inner classes requiring an already existing instance, thus creating a chicken-and-egg problem.

As you already found out you cannot declare the inner class `static` as `Stage` is non-`static` and Java doesn’t allow `static` members in non-`static` inner classes but it wouldn’t help anyway as if the inner classes were `static` they had no outer `Action` instance as well which is what your attempt is all about. Otherwise you could simply use my solution above which already deals with the fact that inner `enum`s are always `static` by introducing a parameter.

So the intended name-space-like nesting only works with `static` inner classes which does not fit well into the idea of using the implicit outer instance:

```
public class ActionB {

  private int m;
  private Stage stage;

  public ActionB() {
      stage = new Implementations.First(this);
  }
  public void proceed() {
      if (stage != null) {
          stage = stage.proceed();
      }
  }

  public abstract class Stage {
    public abstract Stage proceed();
    ActionB outer() { return ActionB.this; }
  }
  static class Implementations {

      public static class First extends Stage {
          First(ActionB outer) { outer.super(); }

          @Override
          public Stage proceed() {
              outer().m = 100;
              return new Second(outer());
          }
      }

      public static class Second extends Stage {
          Second(ActionB outer) { outer.super(); }

          @Override
          public Stage proceed() {
              //do something
              return null; // last stage
          }
      }
  }
}
```

If you go that far, it’s better to use my first suggested solution together with a front-end class providing the desired no-arg method:

```
public class Action {

  private int m;
  private Stage stage;

  public Action() {
      stage = new Stage(StageImpl.FIRST);
  }
  public void proceed() {
      if (stage != null) {
          stage = stage.proceed();
      }
  }

  public class Stage {
    final StageImpl stage;
    Stage(StageImpl next) {
      stage=next;
    }
    public Stage proceed() {
      StageImpl next=stage.proceed(Action.this);
      return next==null? null: new Stage(next);
    }
  }
  enum StageImpl {
    FIRST {
      @Override
      StageImpl proceed(Action a) {
        a.m = 100;
        return SECOND;
      }
    },
    SECOND {
      @Override
      StageImpl proceed(Action a) {
        //do something
        return null; // last stage
      }
    }
    ;
    abstract StageImpl proceed(Action a);
  }
}
```

So you have caged the implementation in some kind of name space (`StageImpl`) and have a front-end class `Stage` which provides the intended `proceed()` method with unchanged semantics.

Comment: Ok this shows that enums can be used instead of simple classes.
But you also changed the `proceed()` method to require the object to work on. This is not necessary in my first example and doing so would make the second example work as well. So a very good hint but I’m still interested to achieve what is tried in the second example.

Comment: @user905686: I have updated my answer. I’m afraid, there is no simple way of fixing your second example.

Comment: If there is no better way, the third solution seems to be the cleanest. Though in my simple example I will use the first solution, because there is only one place where the `proceed()` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can create local variables which are each a Stage implementation. So you don't have the inner classes (named) and this code works.
Personally I think you have simple action engine and would make a distinction between the the framework and the implementations. For example the proceed() method I should move that an ActionRunner class.

```
public class Action
{
   private int m;
   private Stage stage;
   private Stage stage1=new Stage() {

       @Override
       public Stage proceed() {
           m = 100;
           return stage2;
       }
   };

   private Stage stage2=new Stage() {

       @Override
       public Stage proceed() {
           //do something
           return null; // last stage
       }
   };

    public Action() {
        stage = stage1;
    }

    public void proceed() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage = stage.proceed();
        }
    }

    public interface Stage {
        /**
         * Executes current stage and returns next stage.
         *
         * @return
         */
        public abstract Stage proceed();
    }
```

}

I first tried to make the Stage implementation static but then they don't have access to the Action class variables.

Comment: This is possible but seems even less useful then my first approach. You simply replace the classes `FirstStage` and `SecondStage` by anonymous classes in the local variables. So we have variable names instead of class names, rather a disadvantage.
I see no advantage in creating a separate ActionRunner, because it is exactly in the `Action` class with its private member where the code should be executed.